# SSL certificate for 3rd party domain pointed at windows azure role

Tags: https, azure

I have a website hosted on Windows Azure. All pages on the website are on HTTPS. The website can be customized with the customization profile being associated with a uri authority. There is a 3rd party that would like to point a url they own to the website. I already have an SSL certificate associated with the default url for the website, and the url in turn points to the Windows Azure appname.cloudapp.net. To make the default certificate work I needed to associated it with the service in the Windows Azure management portal. For the 3rd party url SSL to work, do I need to add their SSL certificate to the management portal as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, the solution is to use a SSL Unified Communications Certificate which uses SANs (Subject Alternate Names) to support multiple domains. [This](http://www.digicert.com/unified-communications-ssl-tls.htm) is an example.